# filtering the filtered result in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filtering

Can someone please help me with this?
I have two comboboxes, `cboSearchby`(which holds the items `1st sem` and `2nd sem`) and `cboSY`(which holds the items `2014-2015` and `2015-2016`)

```
conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
conn.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
sSQL = "SELECT edp_number, LastName + ', ' + FirstName as name, course as course, Address as address, syear as syear, Sem as sem FROM tblStudent"
If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "1st" And Me.cboSY.Text = "2014-2015" Then
    sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '1st" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%' and syear like '2014-2015" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
Else
    sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '2nd" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%' and syear like '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
End If
```

Now what happens is that when I choose the SY `2015-2016` and choose `1st sem`, which is no record at all, it still shows the SY `2015-2016` with the record of `2nd sem` because it corresponds to the SY `2015-2016` even though they're the record for `2nd sem` and I chose `1st sem`.

So what I want to know is how to make the result available only to the specific SY and corresponding semester chosen either 1st or 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in your code at your End If and then debug the page. When you hit your breakpoint, view the value of cmd.text, cboSY.Text, and cboSearchBy.text in the watch window.

You should know after looking at the contents of cmd.text if the problem is with your sql, or if the problem is elsewhere.

Check the values passed by your comboboxes to make sure that you're getting the value of the controls' selected item

```
Me.cboSY.selecteditem.tostring()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply sir, but I'm just a beginner in programming, I don't understand your instructions above. Can you make it clearer for me sir.

Comment: Assuming you're working in Visual Studio, just google "debugging in visual studio". You'll use what you learn over and over again. Then change use the selected item property of the comobox in your if statement. Me.cboSearchBy.Text becomes Me.cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString() and Me.cboSySearch.text becomes Me.cboSySearch.SelectedItem.tostring()

Comment: thank you so much sir ! the issue has been solve but i'll still accept the answer for your reputation :)